# Can I buy a car in the Kurdistan Region of Iraq, and take it to Turkey?

Tags: passport, paperwork, car, turkish-citizens

As a Turkish citizen, would I be able to buy, insure, and register a car in the Kurdistan Region of Iraq? Luxury vehicles (and the petrol/gasoline prices) are much less expensive there than in Turkey.

When I enter on my Turkish passport, the passport stamp says that you have to visit the Directorate of Residence within 10 days of entering the country. Does that mean you're allowed to purchase a vehicle, too?

It is possible to take the car with you when you return to Turkey? Turkish laws allows you to drive a foreign plated car up to 24 months (2 years).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question a bit, to encourage a response. Should I have misinterpreted or altered your intent, you can undo/rollback to the original.